# Changes to Core Data are not saved when use deletedObjects:entity.attributeName

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to delete the value of some Attributes in two linked Entities. Here is the code I am using:

```
+ (MeetPhoto *)deletePhotoForSelectedMeet:(MarksFromMeets *)specificMeet
                   inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
{
    MeetPhoto *results = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MarksFromMeets"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uniqueResultID = %@", specificMeet.uniqueResultID];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"uniqueResultID" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (!matches || [matches count] > 1) {
        NSLog(@"There has been an error in matches in %@: \n%@.\n matches count = %lu",
              NSStringFromClass([self class]),
              NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),
              (unsigned long)[matches count]);
    } else if ([matches count] == 0){
        NSLog(@"There were no matches in %@: \n%@.\n matches count = %lu",
              NSStringFromClass([self class]),
              NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),
              (unsigned long)[matches count]);
    } else {
        if (debug == 1) NSLog(@"In %@ and matches = %lu",NSStringFromClass([self class]),(unsigned long)[matches count]);

        for (MarksFromMeets* meetEntity in matches) {

            if (debug == 1) NSLog(@" MarksFromMeet = %@ \n thumbnail = %@ \n photo = %@",meetEntity.meetName,meetEntity.photoThumbNail,meetEntity.whichPhoto.photo);

            [context deleteObject:meetEntity.photoThumbNail];
            [context deleteObject:meetEntity.whichPhoto.photo];
            NSError *mySavingError = nil;
            [meetEntity.managedObjectContext save:&mySavingError];
            if (mySavingError) NSLog(@"In %@ and mySavingError is %@",NSStringFromClass([self class]), mySavingError);
        }

    }

    return results;
}
```

Where whichPhoto is the title of the link between the two Core Data Entities.

Here is NSLog Statement:

```
2014-08-13 14:40:45.334 ITrackXC[12054:60b] thisMeetsPhoto should equal nil and equals (null)
2014-08-13 14:41:37.095 ITrackXC[12054:60b] In MeetPhotoViewController and executing imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:
2014-08-13 14:41:37.583 ITrackXC[12054:60b] In MeetPhoto and matches = 1
2014-08-13 14:41:37.589 ITrackXC[12054:60b]  whichMeetPhotographed = <MarksFromMeets: 0x1700c5be0> (entity: MarksFromMeets; id: 0xd000000000300004 <x-coredata://ED56838C-9F27-451D-97CA-01AF0FC38830/MarksFromMeets/p12> ; data: {
    athleteGrade = "12th Grade";
    event = "5000 Meters";
    eventPR = 1;
    eventSB = 1;
    markInEvent = "19:03";
    meetDate = "2013-11-02 07:00:00 +0000";
    meetID = 78103;
    meetName = "OSAA 3A/2A/1A State Championships";
    photoThumbNail = "<UIImage: 0x170281b80>";
    placeInEvent = 2;
    raceSorter = 5000;
    seasonName = 2013;
    sortMark = 1143;
    standardOrMetric = nil;
    uniqueResultID = 10032696;
    whichPhoto = "0x178236d80 <x-coredata:///MeetPhoto/t9C5E481D-5911-47C9-AA8B-6015AAD1C23C2>";
    whoRan = "0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://ED56838C-9F27-451D-97CA-01AF0FC38830/AthleteInfo/p2>";
}) 
 photo = <UIImage: 0x17009b440> 
 thumbnail = <UIImage: 0x170281b80>
2014-08-13 14:41:37.599 ITrackXC[12054:60b] NSManagedObjects did change.
2014-08-13 14:41:39.444 ITrackXC[12054:60b] NSManagedContext did save.
```

I do not get any errors. However when I look at the TableView where the data is displayed, the photos are still part of the record.

I can get rid of the thumbnail and associated photo by setting them to "nil". Is there any problem with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting attribute values to nil is how you're supposed to do this, so no, there's no problem with it. The `deleteObject:` method is only for when you want to delete a managed object. Using it in other cases might not crash, but it also won't have the effect you're aiming for.

In the case of the photo, you *might* need to delete an object, but it's hard to tell from your code. You seem to want to get rid of `meetEntity.whichPhoto.photo`. I don't know what `whichPhoto` is; if it's a managed object, you *might* want to call `deleteObject` on `myEntity.whichPhoto` to get rid of it. If nobody else is using it, that is.

Comment: Tom, I was trying to implement Apple's Core Data Transformable Attributes example. whichPhoto is one side of a link between Core Data Entities. The main entity (table) has all the info and a transformable version of a thumbnail.

The MeetPhoto entity has the actual (transformable) photo. 

What I am concerned about is having "deleted" photos hanging around consuming space. 

Apple's approach seemed cumbersome, so I created a Category for my NSManagedObject subclasses and tried to do the creation and deletion in that. 

I can post more code if you think it would be helpful. Thanks!